# Field 'id' expected a number but got 'category.id'

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm trying to make a category in the DB, but when I try to access the category with the model that entered. it showing me this Error: *ValueError at /category/Django/*

Django is category I entered with the model I made using a ForeignKey.

I tried a different method for the category but it didn't work either.
so I think the problem is in the db.sqlite3 file or in the migrations files.
I can't delete the sql3 db file, I have data that I can't easy replaces.
I don't think the problem is in the settings.py, I tried to change it before and got the same outcome.

**the full Error:**

```
\Python39\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\Users\HPi5\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_lookups.py", line 117, in get_prep_lookup
    self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "C:\Users\HPi5\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1825, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'published'.
```

here is the **views.py** for the category

```
class CatListView(ListView):
    template_name = "Blog/category.html"
    context_object_name = 'catlist'

    def get_queryset(self):
        content = {
            'cat': self.kwargs['category'],
            'posts': Post.objects.filter(category__name=self.kwargs['category']).filter(category='published')
        }
        return content


def category_list(request):
    category_list = Category.objects.exclude(name='default')
    context = {
        "category_list": category_list,
    }
```

the **urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
 path("category/<category>/", views.CatListView.as_view(), name="category"),
]
```

and for the **category.html**

```
{% for post in catlist.posts %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Update:**

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    

class Post(models.Model): 
 
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    werkstoffnummer = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.werkstoffnummer

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

Comment: what are you trying to filter here? Since category is a foreign key, what are field on the foreign model do you want to be published?

Comment: I want to filter the posts based on each category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Post.objects.filter(category__name=self.kwargs['category'])` part alone is already filtering the posts based on the `category` from your key word arguments.
If you only want to filter posts with `published` category name only, you can `category__name="Published"`.

Not entirely sure if that answers your question so comment if thats not it.

Comment: I deleted this part `.filter(category='published')`
and it's working well, but now the ordering is not working properly, and when I set a paginate argument, it pop out this error  `unhashable type: 'slice'`

Comment: @ZakMeshou can you share the code and the argument you passed for that ?

Comment: its the same code in views.py just add   
`ordering = ["-date_posted"] paginate_by = 100`

Comment: oh, get_queryset must return a queryset (you are returning a dictionary). I think you wanted to get_context instead?

Comment: yes, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
.filter(category='published')
```

You are trying to `filter` a `QuerySet` of `Post` objects by `category`. But `category` is a `ForeignKey` field that accepts only `id` or `Category` objects. You are trying to pass there `string` - `'published'`. It cannot be that way.

Comment: so, what should I do ?

Comment: I guess you want to include only `published` Posts. I need to see how do you store such attribute (probably models.py). Maybe it's `.filter(published=True)`

Answer (score 0):

```py
class CatListView(ListView):
    template_name = "Blog/category.html"
    context_object_name = 'catlist'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 100

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(category__name=self.kwargs['category'])

    def get_context(self, **kwargs):
      context = super().get_context(**kwargs)
      paginator = self.get_paginator()
      context.update({
        'cat': self.kwargs['category'],
        'posts': paginator.get_page(self.kwargs[self.page_kwarg]).object_list,
      })
      return context
```

The `get_queryset` will filter the `Post` models before they are paginated. Then inside the `get_context`, the `paginator.get_page`  will get the correct page (based on the url param `self.page_kwarg` which by default is like `?page=2`), and update the context dictionary with the latest results.

For reference on Class based view methods, I recommend you check out: https://ccbv.co.uk/

Comment: it didn't work, in the page no posts appeared